# C#: Pass reflection type into class constructor

Tags: c#, reflection

I've got a generic method that takes an arbitrary JObject (from JSON.net) and converts it into the generically typed object.

So, let's simplify my conversion method to look like the following:

```
private async Task<T> ConvertToObject(JObject obj) {
    //Lots of other stuff yielding in the creation of newObj
    var result = newObj.ToObject<T>();
    return result;
}
```

Now this method works fine as-is, but I want to modify the method so I can properly do the same for complex properties within the generic object that aren't available in my JObject (e.g. I have to look them up separately, do this same conversion and apply to this object result).

My approach so far is to loop through all the properties, identify the complex types, perform the lookup to retrieve their values from my data store, then execute the above against them (potentially recursively if they too have any complex objects), then write that value back out to this complex property, repeat for any others and then as before, return that result.

I'm retrieving the properties via Reflection:

```
var properties = result.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (var property in properties) {
  if (IsSimple(property.PropertyType)
    continue;

  //Do external lookup

  var convertedValue = new ConversionTool<>().Lookup(query);
}
```

Now, that last line is where I'm having my problem. I'm expected to pass a class name into this, not just a type, but I only know the type at runtime per the reflection methods above. I found a post at http://www.paulbatum.com/2008/08/less-fragile-way-to-invoke-generic.html detailing how to make this work if I were simply passing the generic type into a method and he explains the issue with using Activator.CreateInstance in the comments, but it seems like I know the type I'd want to put there - I just don't know it until it runs (and I retrieve it via reflection).

This seems like an issue that ORMs would run into when it comes to populating complex properties of their entities, but I'm having a difficult time finding how they're doing this.

Given that the caller of this method is aware at runtime what the intended type is, how might I go about passing that type into the generic class constructor so I might call it recursively for each complex member of a given type?

Comment: In short Generics are not generic at run time, at compile time 'Thing<T>' becomes a concrete static type of 'Thing<MyType>` or whatever instance you created. So you can't do it at run time, thats not what generics are about. You could potentially generate a new type and load it in dynamically maybe but I have no idea if that would be possible or even make sense, this might clear things up https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generics-in-the-run-time

Comment: If you've got an object and you don't know its type, that's really the problem to solve. If you're discovering what type something is at runtime, then what will you do with the object? Passing it to another method or doing anything else to it at runtime requires writing code that compiles. But how can you write or compile the code when you don't know what the object is? That's not an impossible problem, but I recommend doing anything you can to avoid having it, because the solution will be brittle and complex. If our code knows what types its operating on everything else becomes simpler.

Comment: Another way of phrasing it: If you're using generics, it's become complicated, and reflection looks like a possible answer, you are on the edge of the [Generic Rabbit Hole of Madness](https://dev.to/scotthannen/the-generic-rabbit-hole-of-madness-2nnn). The best thing is to step back and try to solve the original problem a completely different way.

Comment: @ScottHannen Ultimately, I know what the type is because the caller knows, and I'm aiming to use generics here so I can avoid making a type-specific solution. Rather, I'd like to just walk down the type provided and run as-is against primitive types and run recursively against complex types to retrieve and map those as well, but that requires passing in the type of the current property into the generic type.

Comment: What about something like: `typeof(ConversionTool<>).MakeGenericType([typeobject]).GetConstructor().Invoke(null);`